# In Elasticsearch, how to exclude search results that 'cross' sentences (full stops)

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I have 4 documents indexed by `Elasticsearch`(using the library`elastic` in `R`.

> library(elastic)
> connection <- connect(errors = "complete")
> indexName <- "test"
> index_create(connection,indexName)
>
> text <- data.frame("full_text"= "this is a brown dog. that likes to be.")
> docs_bulk(connection,text,indexName)
> text <- data.frame("full_text"= "This is a brown dog. that likes to be.")
> docs_bulk(connection,text,indexName)
> text <- data.frame("full_text"= "THIS is a brown dog. that likes to be.")
> docs_bulk(connection,text,indexName)
> text <- data.frame("full_text"= "THIS a brown dog is. that likes to be.")
> docs_bulk(connection,text,indexName)
> text <- data.frame("full_text"= "ia THIS a brown dog. that likes to be.")
> docs_bulk(connection,text,indexName)
> text <- data.frame("full_text"= "is THIS a brown dog. that likes to be.")
> docs_bulk(connection,text,indexName)
> text <- data.frame("full_text"= "is THIS a brown dog. that likse to be.")
> docs_bulk(connection,text,indexName)
> text <- data.frame("full_text"= "is THIS a brown dog. that like to be.")
> docs_bulk(connection,text,indexName)
> text <- data.frame("full_text"= "is THIS a brown dog. that likes to be.")
> docs_bulk(connection,text,indexName)
> text <- data.frame("full_text"= "is apple THIS a brown dog. thats like to be.")
> docs_bulk(connection,text,indexName)
> text <- data.frame("full_text"= "is THIS a brown dog. apple that likes to be.")
> docs_bulk(connection,text,indexName)
> text <- data.frame("full_text"= "is THIS a brown dog. apple that likes to be.")
> docs_bulk(connection,text,indexName)
> text <- data.frame("full_text"= "is THIS a brown dog apple that likes to be.")
> docs_bulk(connection,text,indexName)

By using the search query: `'dog MUST PRECEDENT that, WITH A MAX_GAP OF 3, BUT MUST NOT INCLUDE .'` I want to find (return) only the last document.

I tried the following search query, but this does not work, that's all 12 documents are returned, because -- if I'm correct -- periods are not indexed by Elasticsearch.

> query <-
> '{
> "from" : 0, "size" : 10000,
> "query": {
> "bool": {
> "must": [
> {
> "intervals" : {
> "full_text" : {
> "all_of" : {
> "ordered" : true,
> "intervals" : [
> {
> "match" : {
> "query" : "dog",
> "max_gaps" : 0,
> "ordered" : true
> }
> },
> {
> "any_of" : {
> "intervals" : [
> { "match" : {
> "query" : "likes",
> "max_gaps" : 0,
> "ordered" : true
>
> ```
>                 }
>               ]
>             }
>           }
>         ],
>         "max_gaps" : 3
>       }
>     }
>   }
>     }
>   ],
>   "must_not": {
>     "match": {
>       "full_text": "."
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> }
> }'
> Search(connection,indexName,body=query)

Next, I included the whitespace analyser before indexing the documents:

> index_create(connection,indexName)
> mapping<- '
> {"properties": {
> "full_text":{
> "type":"text",
> "analyzer": "whitespace"}
> }
> }
> '
> mapping_create(
> connection,
> indexName,
> body=mapping
> )

Interestingly, two documents are returned: the last one (correct), and this one `"THIS a brown dog is. that likes to be."`

I assume that this this document is returned because the `.` is included in `is.` and not in `that`.

Any hints on how to proceed are very welcome. If I need to provide more info, just let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to input from several users on reddit, I was able to solve the problem.

See: https://www.reddit.com/r/elasticsearch/comments/15z3g97/in_elasticsearch_how_to_exclude_search_results/?sort=new

Will post a clean example later here.